# Настройка кэширования страниц

Tags: html, кэширование

Есть один сайт на umi-cms, главная страница этого сайта меняется с завидным постоянством: меняются баннеры, их расположение, размер, в следствии чего меняется и каскадные таблицы стилей для нее. И тут возникает проблема с кэшированием страниц сайта. В самой cms кэширование отключено, в заголовок страницы поставлено:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, max-age=0,   must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"/>
```

Но это никак не влияет на кэширование, т.е. все браузеры стабильно не отображают изменений, помогает только если сбросить кэш принудительно. Как я понимаю, изменения не отображаются нормально, т.к. кэшируется файлы каскадных таблиц стилей, которые подключаются отдельно. Как можно сообщить браузеру, чтобы он не кэшировал их, а переписывал заново каждый раз? Вообще возможно ли силами html настроить кэширование только для одной страницы(т.к. фактически изменяется только главная), если нет, то можно ли сделать это через .htaccess для одной страницы?

Comment: Разбейте текст на абзацы.

Comment: @w00f, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Для CSS есть простой способ - добавить как бы параметр:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css?v777" />
```

Браузер будет воспринимать это, как новый файл и не будет использовать закэшированную копию

Comment: В общем похоже, что для проблемы с css  я нашел решение, достаточно в папку с ними поместить .htaccess с запретом кэширования:

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header append Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
</IfModule>
 
# Заголовок Expires
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On ExpiresDefault "now"
</IfModule>

Но остатся еще проблема, что мета тэги в заголовках страницы попросту не действуют, какие нужны мета теги, чтобы страница гарантированно не кэшировалась браузером?

Answer (score 0):

Для кеширования гораздо правильнее и надёжнее правильно настроить отправку http-заголовков, а не расставлять meta-теги по html-разметке.

Во-первых, даже браузеры не очень-то и обязаны обрабатывать эти meta-теги. Во-вторых, кеширование на основе заголовков возможно на всяческих прокси-серверах, которые не парсят содержимое. Соответственно, даже если браузер подумал и перезапросил содержимое, то первый же прокси может отдать ему закешированную версию.

Ну и естественно, meta-теги в разметке вообще никак не влияют на остальное загружаемое содержимое типа стилей, скриптов и картинок.